# Google Analytics API - How to calculate average page depth

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to determine how to calculate the **average** page depth for all sessions, daily, for a range of dates. I know that GA has a dimension named ga:pageDepth, but this is not the average page depth. This just returns the number of sessions that had a page depth of 1, and 2, and 3 etc. What I would like is something returned like this:

```
December 1, 2015: 10
December 2, 2015: 9
```

Where 10 and 9 represent the average page depth for all sessions.

I've been using the Google Analytics API ([Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/#report-end)) but cannot find a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would be a good job for a calculated metric - that's a relatively new feature in GA that allows you to create your own metric from existing ones.

Go to your account, admin, view settings, calulacted metric, formatting type "float" and formula "{{Page Views}} / {{Sessions}}" (or whatever, there is an autosuggest feature for all metric names you can use). For use with the API there is an "external name" field (which will default to the name field in the name field with the calcMetric-prefix). In the interface this is available instantly after you created it (so it obviously works on historic data), however I'm not sure it will show up in the query explorer (I created a test metric 10 minutes or so ago and I don't see it in the query explorer. However API use is explicitly mentioned in the docs, so it should be available).

[image]

In my accounts this is still marked as "beta" so I'm not sure it's already been rolled out to all GA accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Pages/Session metric. It's already there....